# R: full_join of two datasets reports more rows than adding those of dataset 1 and dataset 2

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, tidyr

I have two datasets. The variable which I am trying to join those datasets by has the following dimensions:
dataset 1 - 100
dataset 2 - 30

Even if there wasn't any intersection the maximum number of rows as a result of using full_joint should be 130, right?

What I get though are *more than 130* rows after joining the datasets, how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have duplicated ids in your datasets. Example :

```r
d1 <- data.frame(id = rep(1,5)) # 5 rows, 1 id
d2 <- data.frame(id = rep(1,5)) # 5 rows, 1 id
d1
d2

merge(d1, d2, by = "id", all = T) # 25 rows = 5 * 5
```

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: It all depends on your data. Do you know why you have duplicates ? It is normal or not ? To keep one raw by id, as a data.table fan, I would use : ```library(data.table) ;
setDT(d1) ;
setDT(d2) ;
d1 <- unique(d1, by = "id") ;
d2 <- unique(d2, by = "id") ;
  
merge(d1, d2, by = "id", all = T) # 1 row``` but there are other ways if you don't want to use data.table

Comment: Hi @ella ! Could you mark the thread as "solved" ?

Comment: Hi @ella ! Could you mark the thread as "solved" ?